# WSGIScriptAlias & DjangoCMS url rewriting

Tags: python, django, apache, url-rewriting, django-cms

I have a django cms site on my VM and a wordpress.
To go to the wordpress site : xx.xx.xx.xx/wordpress, this works fine, thanks to the alias.
To go to the djangoCMS site : xx.xx.xx.xx/djangocms

And here, djangocms rewrite the url :
xx.xx.xx.xx/en/djangocms
and i would like to have : xx.xx.xx.xx/djangocms/en/

here is my apache conf :

```
WSGIScriptAlias /djangocms "/var/www/djangocms/apache/django.wsgi"
<Directory "/var/www/djangocms/">
Options +ExecCGI
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>

Alias /wordpress "/var/www/wordpress/"
```

my urls.py :

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = i18n_patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^', include('cms.urls')),
)

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
        {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True}),
    url(r'', include('django.contrib.staticfiles.urls')),
) + urlpatterns

#my django.wsgi
import os
import sys

os.environ['HTTPS'] = "on"
path = '/var/www/djangocms/'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.insert(0, '/var/www/djangocms/')

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'djangocms.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

Anyone know how to add /en/ after /djangocms/ ?
thanks ;)

Comment: Thank you, your apache conf details helped me setting up my django application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with :

```
Redirect /en/django /django/en
```